# How does Collections.sort work behind the scenes?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, collections, big-o

Can someone trying to explain me how Collections.sort works behind the scenes and why its algorithm complexity is O( n log n)?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java) is the source code